# Pytorch Runtime Error: efficientnet freeze layers by setting requires grad = false

Tags: pytorch, data-science, torch, torchvision

I want to freeze the layers in pytorch efficentnet model. My usual way of dooing this doesn't work.

```
from torchvision.models import efficientnet_b0
from torch import nn
from torch import optim

efficientnet_b0_fine = efficientnet_b0(pretrained=True)

for param in efficientnet_b0_fine.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False

efficientnet_b0_fine.fc = nn.Linear(512, 10)

optimizer = optim.Adam(efficientnet_b0_fine.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

training(net=efficientnet_b0_fine, n_epochs=epochs, optimizer=optimizer, loss_function=loss_function, train_dl = train_dl)
```

The Error I get says:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

The Training function looks like this:

```
for xb, yb in train_dl:
  optimizer.zero_grad()  
  xb = xb.to(device)
  yb = yb.to(device)

  y_hat = net(xb)  
  loss = loss_function(y_hat, yb) 
  
  loss.backward()  
  optimizer.step()
```

Would be great if one of you has a solution!

Comment: can you check whether `efficientnet_b0_fine.fc.parameters()` require grad after your setup

Comment: Could you check wheter `loss` has a `grad_fn` attribute?

Comment: Yes, there are parameters that require grad, aprox. 5000.

Comment: No, loss has no grad_fn attribute, but does when I use for e.g. resnet50